# How to remove all comments in .cs files in VS2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Is there anyway or any addin for VS2010 that can remove all the comments in the .cs file including "/// Summary" and "//"?

I don't want to do it manully foreach .cs files.

Comment: @ChrisBint: Not necessarily. Many comments are unnecessary, get outdated or may just be confusing. Clean code needs less comments, and as we clean up our code, we regularly remove old comments that have lost their meaning. 

Some however, may still be useful, so removing all automatically sounds quite drastic. I would search the solution for all comments, then go through the files quickly but orderly, and remove anything that appears useless using the **Ctrl+L** shortcut (remove line) - probably the quickest _controlled_ way to do it.

Comment: @ChrisBint Reading other people's code - cluttered with every single line is trivially "commented" on the statement level is a pain in the, you know where... If a comment sums up some lines, OK. If it gives you the intention or reason why its done exactly that way, yay, that's what its for. In some cases you simply want to concentrate on the code as it is the best documentation for the actual behavior of e.g. a public API. To me, a "view" would suffice in most cases - if the comments are correct (and up-to-date).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want it, you get it. Firstly read this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2k3te2cs.aspx
You exactly need expression that will match to the end of the line.

And replace it with `' '` or etc.
And then you follow this manual http://geekswithblogs.net/MarkPearl/archive/2011/04/12/vs2010-multiline-find-amp-replace.aspx
and replace all.

Answer (score 1):

I'd second to Feanor. You can record a macro, like search for comment '//' and then delete that line (Ctrl+L). Edit the macro to put that in a loop. Then run this macro for each file.

If you can spend some more time in writing macro, you can loop through the Projects and ProjectItems. So that will remove comment lines from entire solution. You can learn more about [EnvDTE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) for that.